# Is the format of Less files and css files the same?

Tags: css, format, less

I am not sure about how to write the contents of a Less file. Can anyone tell me if the css format (way in which we write in css files) is the same as that for a less file, and if all css content is compatible with Less files.

Thanks in advance. please help.

Comment: Any valid CSS is valid LESS. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `less` and `css` file is for same purpose. `css` coding structure is valid on `less` file. but `less` coding structure may not valid on `css` file. `Less` is advance. Main theory is `write less and do more`. Something like dynamic `css`.

css file extension is `.css` and `rel="stylesheet"`

less file extension is `.less` and  `rel="stylesheet/less"`

Answer (score 3):

Every valid CSS file is also a valid Less file.

Less was deliberately designed so that its syntax is a super-set of CSS syntax.

This makes is easy to migrate your existing CSS files to Less - initially you can just rename the files and wire up the transform. Then you can incrementally introduce Less features, such as nesting and variables, into the code to tidy it up.